# Is there a jqueryUi.mouse.js version for jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-mobile

I use a jqueryui.sortable widget for my site, and it doesn't work in mobile platforms. I looked through source code, and looks like it's `mouse.js` that binds handlers to events.

Is there a version of mouse.js for jQ mobile, or is there a simple way to translate jq mobile events (vmousedown, vmousemove, vmouseup) into usual mouse events, so that jQuery UI widgets receive them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably extend the library yourself without too much work.

The check for if the device support touch or not is easy:

```
var supportTouch = ("ontouchend" in document);
```

Then you can use the appropriate event based on if touch is enabled or not, the following is used in jQuery mobiles library:

```
var touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
    touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
    touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
```

Then you change the library to use those variables instead of the current hardcoded mouse events, probably looks something like this:

```
$(".sortable").bind("mousedown", doSomething());
```

But should look like this:

```
$(".sortable").bind(touchStartEvent, doSomething());
```

Do some testing before you do too much work, I have not tested the above code and not looked at the sortable library.

Another note is that some mobile devices don't support dragging of objects in the browser, one I know about is Windows Phone 7 (both with and without Mango). If you want to support those you should build some "non drag and drop" solution.

Comment: I just changed the event names to 'v*', but this code looks better, thanks!